# Confused about topological definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I'm a bit confused by the topological definition of continuity:
$f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if $\forall V \subseteq Y$ open, $f^{-1}(V)$ is also open. If I define a function like $$f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      x & x\leq 0, \\
      x+1 & x>0 .
   \end{cases}
$$

Then the range $Y$ is $(-\infty,0] \cup (1,\infty).$ How do I select an open set in that range that has a non-open inverse image? The discontinuity is at $x=0$, but no open set in $Y$ will map back to that point. Obviously, if I choose an open set in the codomain $\mathbb{R}$ like $(-1,2)$ then the inverse image is non-open ($f^{-1}((-1,2))=(-1,0]\cup(1,2)) $.

Comment: The definition of a continuous function assumes that topologies for $X$ and $Y$ have already been specified. What topology are we using for $Y$?

Comment: I should clarify that I'm implicitly negating the definition here. Explicitly, discontinuous would be defined as $f:X\rightarrow Y $ is not continuous if $\exists V \subseteq Y $ open, but $f^{-1}(V)$ is not open.

Comment: @littleO I think this might be the piece I was missing. If I define the topology on $Y$ as the union of all open intervals on the real line, then it isn't continuous, but if I restrict the topology to the union of all open intervals drawn from $(-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)$, then it would be continuous?

Comment: It would be natural to use the subspace topology for $Y$.

Comment: think of $f$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, for example. then what's the preimage of the open set $(-\infty,1/2)$? equivalently, if you want to think of $f$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to its range, then you should consider the range $(-\infty,0]\cup (1,\infty)$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$; in this space $(-\infty,0]$ is an open subset, and what is its preimage under $f$?

Comment: (these examples are the "same" because the intersection of the open subset $(-\infty,1/2)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with the subspace $(-\infty,0]\cup(1,\infty)$ is the subset $(-\infty,0]$, which is hence open in the subspace topology)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $V = (-\infty,1)$. Then $f^{-1}(V) = (-\infty,0]$ which is not open.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was confused because $(-\infty,1)$ is not in the range of the function, but considering $(-\infty,0]\cup(1,\infty)$ with the subspace topology inhereted from $\mathbb{R}$, one can construct an open interval in this topological subspace (say, $(-\infty,0]$) that has a non-open preimage.